# How to serve a JS file to every browser but IE

Tags: javascript, conditional-comments

I dont know why this isn't working. I'm trying to serve a file to good browsers, namely everyone but IE.

```
<!--[if !IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/script.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

but it doesn't get served to any...any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->

<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Missing trailing -->

Comment: Man that was stupid. 18hrs later and im that guy. thx for the push.